# Mac: Text-to-Speech: How to add abbreviations to the TTS functionality?

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

At MacOS the Text-to-Speech (TTS, Apple's Speech Synthesis) functionality already knows some abbreviations but important stuff is missing (e.g. the paragraph symbol). I like to add some more abbreviations etc. because otherwise (in case of abbreviations) it just reads the letters which is not helpful.
First I thought the Voice-over Utility would be the right place to add them but it isn't.
So, how can I add abbreviations (and other e.g. not correctly pronounced words) to get it spoken correctly by the Text-to-Speech functionality.

Does the file /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks//SpeechDictionary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/HomophonesEng play a role for that?
If yes, (as this seems only relevant for English) where are German words handled?

Thanks for help, mbxx